# Relation between terminal voltage and charging speed in Lithium-Ion batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I tested charging a 5200 mAh (20 Wh) battery at 10W.

Its State of Charge level at the beginning was 20%. The terminal voltage was 3.68 V. Now, I applied 10 W of charging power to the battery. After some time, the terminal voltage rises to 3.94 V, which means that it rose by **0.26 V.**

Let's increase the charging power until the terminal voltage increases by **0.26 V** again, to 4.2 V of terminal voltage.

#### Is the charging power now 20 Wh or higher?

- **00** Watts at 3.68 Volts
- **10** Watts at 3.94 Volts
- **??** Watts at 4.20 Volts ?

Is there a formula for that?

Comment: *Now, I applied 10W of charging rate to the battery.* Watch your units! Do you mean charging the battery at a current such that voltage times current equals 10 W? If so, then for how long? Watt is energy **per second** so we need to know the seconds.

Comment: The charging rate expressed in watts as from your example is: Voltage * Current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for the link. This is the answer.

Comment: Converted that comment into an answer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Great. I marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries ?

Look at a typical Lithium based cell charging curve:

[image]

Note how the charge level to voltage relation is very non-linear. When the battery is at a low charge the voltage increases more quickly with charge level compared to an almost full battery. So to get from 3.94 V to 4.20 V more energy is needed than going from 3.68 V to 3.94 V. So charging with another 10 W during one hour (1 Whr) will result in a lower voltage than 4.20 V

Answer (score 0):

> Is the charging power now 20 Wh or higher?

It can be anything. You can continue charging at 0.1 W, 1 W, 10 W, or whatever power you wish. It just affects how long it takes to charge from 3.94 V to 4.20 V.

I think you are confusing "power" (energy per time) and "energy". You can achieve a given amount of energy stored with any amount of power, as long as you do it long enough.